# 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListner through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Would be really glad if some one can take me out of this error :(

```
dgfdHome.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK, chome);
function chome(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `addEventListener` instead of `addEventListner` ;)